# Make unchecked Radio buttons and associated Text disappear?

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

Say I have 2 sets of 3 radio buttons with the same name.  Let us name them "set1" and "set2".

What I want to do is 1: When the user presses my CallFunction() button all radio buttons will disappear (or become unclickable) and 2: only the unselected options text (right of the radio in HTML) will disappear while the user's checked selections remain visible.

Please help, I'm beginning to think this is impossible without a ridiculous amount of getElementByIds...

...or should I give up on the same page idea and just use Submit?

Comment: You should use jQuery, it'll make your life much easier. Also, can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/yyACY/

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="butt" value="CallFunction()   :P" />
<div id="rads">
    <input type="radio" class="rad" name="set1" value="1" /><span class="set1">1</span><br />
    <input type="radio" class="rad" name="set1" value="2" /><span class="set1">2</span><br />
    <input type="radio" class="rad" name="set1" value="3" /><span class="set1">3</span><br /><br />
    <input type="radio" class="rad" name="set2" value="1" /><span class="set2">1</span><br />
    <input type="radio" class="rad" name="set2" value="2" /><span class="set2">2</span><br />
    <input type="radio" class="rad" name="set2" value="3" /><span class="set2">3</span><br /><br />
</div>
```

**Javascript (Jquery)**

```
$("#butt").click(function(){
    $("#rads").css('display', 'none');
});

$(".rad").click(function(){
    var spans = "." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(spans).css('display', 'none');
    $(this).next().css('display', '');
});
```